# What is value ui-c in span class?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We are using JSF and PrimeFaces for our front end and for checkbox. I'm having the following issue:

I don't know from where `ui-c` values coming into span class (I checked using F12) and due to this I'm not able to select the checkbox.

If I remove the above value (tested using F12), then I'm able to click it.

```html
<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
```

After F12,

```html
<span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
```

Please let me know how to deal with `ui-c`.

Comment: They come from PrimeFaces 'Renderers' but only if you are using a very old version. Recent ones don't have this

Comment: We are using 6.1, it's latest one I think. Is there any way to override this ui-c and make it work?

Comment: Is this just in the selection column or in others too?

Comment: It's just for selection column, if I click on other column this checkbox gets selected but not when I click on checkbox itself then it's not working due to ui-c

Comment: Is there alao ui-c in the other colums? And you write checkbox but you mean radiobutton I assume

Comment: yes correct, checkbox with radiobutton.

Comment: Stil a 'strange' remark, "Checkbox with radiobutton", you most likely mean a 'selection column with a radiobutton"... Can you check 6.2 (just for this case) which is btw the latest) I cannot see a ui-c in there in the https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: Oh and what do you mean by _"If I remove above value"_ I don't see any 'value' or something like it above your comment

Comment: I mean, the values in span class are as per follows,                                     
  <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span> and if I remove ui-c from sapn class then it's working(I'm able to select checkbox). Is there any way to remove only this value while rendering the page?

Comment: `selectionmode="single"` renders radiobuttons, not checkboxes. Tried removing the CSS, does it work then?

Comment: I found some workaround :)                                                                           
               <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
        $("span").removeClass("ui-c"); 
    }());   
         </script>

Comment: Yes but if this is normally there you should just be able to click it unless somw custom css prevents this.

Comment: @Kukeltje: The `ui-c` class is there on the showcase as well. See https://imgur.com/a/1hoMZTp

Comment: @Abhishek: You should try looking for the styles applied over that `ui-c` class in your CSS that might be causing issue in selection. Meanwhile, there is none CSS definition over that class on showcase.

Comment: I was not talking about that Class I was talking about custom styling just like you do Now. Might even be styling on the span It Self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was, added fuction to remove this corrupted class

```
function removeCorruptedCssClass() {
            $("span").removeClass("ui-c");
        }           
        $(document).ready( removeCorruptedCssClass );
```

Comment: Why do you think it is corrupt? Please note that removing classes might break component functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why `ui-c` is an issue. Anyway, it is rendered on this line

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5b9ad5e63e4cc66e9ef51d5217b189a2aed9d23c/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/radiobutton/RadioButtonRenderer.java#L140

If there is an issue because of this class, first try if you have the same issue with the current version of PrimeFaces, if it persists, please [report it](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues). Tampering with classes which were added by PrimeFaces might break components.